# i am trying to connect sql and python and trying to display the database with pretty table but this error is occurring

Tags: python, sql, mysql-python, prettytable

```
t = x(['Emp.no','Emp_name','Designation','Salary','Commission'])
TypeError: 'PrettyTable' object is not callable
```

Comment: Just a guess, try removing the period from Emp.no.

Comment: Show us where `x` comes from.